# Data table generated from Firebase cannot be displayed stably

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, frontend

I need to develop a mobile app that features a leaderboard. The leaderboard only displays on one tab, however, every time when I return to this page from another tab, the leaderboard always fades away immediately (Please have a look at this [screen record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TGWi9a5Sy8nDzY_HZ1CBt2Oeq2Y5y6U2/view?usp=sharing)). Is there a way to make the data shown stably?

Here is my code snippet:

```
// LeaderboardView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct Leaderboard: View {
    @ObservedObject private var users = UserViewModel()
    var body: some View {
// ...
            NavigationView {
                List(users.topFiveUsers) {
                    user in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(verbatim: user.name).font(.headline)
                            Text(verbatim: String(user.xp)).font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Leaderboard"))
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}

struct Leaderboard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Leaderboard()
    }
}
```

```
// UserViewModel.swift

import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var topFiveUsers = [User]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users")
        
    public init() {
        let top5 = db.order(by: "xp", descending: true).limit(to: 5)
        top5.addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = QuerySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Document is empty")
                return
            }
            self.topFiveUsers = documents.map {
                (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> User in
                let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let xp = data["xp"]
                let name = data["username"]
                return User(name:name as? String ?? "", xp:xp as? Int ?? 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// User.swift

import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class User : ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var bio = ""
    @Published var interest = ""
    @Published var level = 1
    @Published var xp = 0
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var image_Data = Data(count: 0)
    @Published var picker = false
    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @AppStorage("status") var status = false
    
    // common init
    init() {
        
    }
    
    //initializer for leaderboard collection
    init(name: String, xp: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.xp = xp
        self.level = User.xp2Level(xp: xp)
    }
}
```

```
// ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    @State var centerX : CGFloat = 0
    @State var goToHome = false
    @State var edge = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
//    @Environement(.verticalSizeClass) var size
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if goToHome {
                
                NavigationView {
                    CustomTabView(centerX: $centerX)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            }
            else {
                OnBoardScreen()
            }
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:Notification.Name("Success")), perform: {
            _ in withAnimation{self.goToHome = true}
        })
    }
        
}

struct CustomTabView : View {
    //swich tabs
    @State var selectedTab = "home"
    @Binding var centerX : CGFloat
    var body : some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)){
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Home()
                    .tag("home")
                Leaderboard()
                    .tag("Leaderboard")
                Pal()
                    .tag("profile")
            }
//            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            
//            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) {image in
                    GeometryReader {reader in
                        TabButton(image: image, centerX: $centerX, rect:reader.frame(in:.global), selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                        //setting initial curve
                            .onAppear(perform: {
                                if image == tabs.first{
                                    centerX = reader.frame(in: .global).midX
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                    if image != tabs.last {Spacer(minLength: 0)}
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
//            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.vertical, 17)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom == 0 ? 15: 0)
            .background(Color("5324FF").clipShape(AnimatedShape(centerX: centerX)))
            .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
//            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
           
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue has to do with the way that you're handling your shown view. The code for the user object, firebase, and the leaderboard itself is not relevant to the issue. Please post code showing how you're displaying the different tab items.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have already edited my question. Please refer to it.

Comment: Agree with what xTwisteDx said - the issues lies with how you handle the selected state of the tab view. I'd recommend setting this up in a smaller repro case so you're not distracted by all the other code. Also, please don't map Firestore data manually - use Codable instead. I wrote a comprehensive guide about that: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/. Also, make sure to map the Firestore document ID against an id attribute on the User to actually make it identifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if @State works, you should use @StateObject. If you use @State, there is a possibility that SwiftUI destroys the Object randomly.

```
@StateObject private var users = UserViewModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the property of the variable `users` in View file from `ObservedObject` to `State`. Then the table became stable.